# Vaadin 6 : Window.open(FileResource) ; how do I monitor download?

Tags: download, vaadin, monitor

I am building a Portlet using Vaadin 6. In the portlet I let the end user download the result of the searches/operations he's done. 
What I am doing here is generate, on the fly, a zip file for download and serve it for download using

> getMainWindow().open(resource);

where resource is a FileResource.

Since the search for is quite complex, I have very little chance to be able to reuse the results and, in order to make things nice,I would like to delete the zip file from the server once it's been "consumed" by the download process.

Is there any chance I can monitor somehow when the download has been completed ?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is just keeping the Server clean, it should be enough to use the tmp-dir of your machine. This Way, the OS handles deletion for you. 
Or you could write your own clean up process either with cron or sheduler/timer services.